# Cmake: don't build project again when executing make install

Tags: java, maven, makefile, build, cmake

I have a CMakeList.txt which will build a Java project with Maven to a war file when running `make`, but when I run `make install`, it will rebuild it again before copy to the installation folder of Web Application.

How can I only build Java once with `make` but not again with `make install`? Here is the CMakeList.txt:

```
add_custom_target(JavaProject ALL
        COMMAND ${MAVEN_EXECUTABLE} package
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        VERBATIM)
install(FILES "${JAVA_PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/java_project.war"
        DESTINATION ${WAR_DIR})
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), especially the explicitly emphasised "is *always considered out of date*" bit?

Comment: ah, yes, thanks for the info, so I need to change to add_custom_command()

Comment: ... and then add a driver for that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation of `add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) says, custom targets are *always considered out of date,* which means they will re-build with each invocation of `make` which includes them.

What you want instead is a custom *command* to produce the `.war` file:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${JAVA_PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/java_project.war"
  COMMAND ${MAVEN_EXECUTABLE} package
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  VERBATIM
)
```

This tells CMake how the file named `"${JAVA_PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/java_project.war"` is produced when someone requests it. For files, CMake can generate dependency checks just fine, so it will not re-build needlessly. Note that you will probably also want to include some `DEPENDS` in that `add_custom_command()`, otherwise it will *never* rebuild once built<sup>(1)</sup>.

Then, you need one more thing: a driver for the custom command. That is something that will depend on the command's `OUTPUT` and actually cause it to be built. So you'll add a custom *target:*

```
add_custom_target(
  JavaProject ALL
  DEPENDS "${JAVA_PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/java_project.war"
)
```

Then, the sequence will be as follows:

During a `make`, `JavaProject` will be considered out of date (since it's a custom target) and will be built. This means its dependencies will be checked for up-to-datedness, and re-built if they're not up to date. That's what the custom command is for. After that, the custom target itself would run its `COMMAND`, but it doesn't have any, so nothing else happens.

On a subsequent `make` invocation, `JavaProject` will again be considered out of date and will thus be built. Its dependencies are checked again, but this time, they're up to date (since the `.war` already exists). It's therefore not built again. The custom target still has no `COMMAND`, so nothing further happens.

This "custom target as driver for custom commands" approach is very a idiomatic piece of CMake code, and you will see it in many projects which produce additional files which do not participate in further build steps (such as documentation).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If the list of dependencies is very large, you want to move it to a separate files and include that. Something like this:

**In `CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
include(files.cmake)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "${JAVA_PROJECT_TARGET_DIR}/java_project.war"
  COMMAND ${MAVEN_EXECUTABLE} package
  DEPENDS ${MyFiles}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  VERBATIM
)
```

**In `files.cmake`:**

```
set(MyFiles
  a/file1.java
  a/file2.java
  a/b/file1.java
  a/c/file1.java
  # ... list all files as necessary
)
```

This keeps the CMakeList itself readable, while allowing you to explicitly depend on all you need.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm really new with Cmake and try to change the build.

Comment: I have a question, please help. As you said in add_custom_command() I probably need to add DEPENDS otherwise it will not built the java_project.war again after I changed some file in the source folder.

It is best if I could make it rebuild java_project if any changes (edit files in the java_project source folder). I tried to add DEPENDS with a specific folder in source folder, it works, but it does not regard changes in subdirectories.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru You have to list individual files there. It's best to have an explicit list, that will force CMake to re-run and update the buildsystem if you add a file to that list.

Comment: I thought Cmake support the wildcard but if not then there is a lot of folder can be changed (so I cannot list in DEPENDS) ;( and when I run make, it will not build again. So your accepted answer has this disadvantage.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru "So I cannot list in `DEPENDS`" I challenge that. At work, we have over a hunderd projects, many of them having hundreds of source files each. We still list those files explicitly, and it works. I will extend the answer with a few words about doing this managably.

Comment: Please see my answer post below, although thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2):

Although Angew has an excellent answer but unfortunately it does not work as I expect (i.e: when update source code folder and run make, it will not build the war again).

Here is the way to solve what I wanted:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY TRUE)
```

Then when I run make it will build and make install will just copy to the installation folder.

Comment: Of course, this means that *every* run of `make` will re-build the `war`. This may be what you want, or not.

Comment: yes, this is what I wanted (it is supposed to rebuild this war file (it is not big enough so I have to list depends as your but if have many then of course will have to do as your answer).